When do quotients of $G$-vector bundles exist?
Let's work in the category of smooth (paracompact, Hausdorff) manifolds. Let $M$ be a manifold and $G$ a Lie group acting on $M$. Suppose $E$ is a $G$-vector bundle on $M$ (that is, $G$ acts on $E$ by bundle automorphisms in a fashion lifting the action on $M$). Suppose $E'$ is a $G$-subbundle of $E$.
What are the most general conditions under which the quotient vector bundle $E/E'$ is a $G$-vector bundle? I.e., under which the $G$-vector bundle structures on $E$ and $E'$ induce a (necessarily unique) $G$-bundle structure on the quotient vector bundle $E/E'$ which satisfies the universal property of the quotient of $E$ by $E'$ in the category  of $G$-vector bundles?
EDIT: as pointed out by nandor below, the $G$-actions on $E$ and $E'$ induce a well-defined pointwise $G$-action on $E/E'$. However, the crux is to prove this action is smooth.
A sufficient condition for this is that $E'$ admit a $G$-invariant complement in $E$. Is this condition also necessary?
If $G$ is compact, then $E/E'$ always exists as a $G$-vector bundle: by averaging with respect to Haar measure, a $G$-invariant bundle metric $h$ exists on $E$ and the $h$-orthocomplement $(E')^\perp$ is a $G$-invariant complement. I'd like to remove the compactness assumption to the extent possible, although I suspect some assumption is needed.
One assumption I'm willing to live with is that $G$ is not necessarily compact, but $M$ is a $G$-principal bundle. In this situation, can one prove that $E/E'$ is a $G$-vector bundle?

What stops you from taking the vector bundle quotient and defining the $G$-action as the quotient action on each fibre?

That defines the $G$-action on $E/E'$ as a set. But how do you show that's a $C^\infty$ action? For this, you have to show $G$ takes a local frame for $E/E'$ to another local frame, and I don't see how to do this without a $G$-invariant complement to $E'$.

What do you mean by a local frame for $E/E'$? I think you mean a list of smooth sections of $E/E'\to M$ defined on an open neighborhood of a specified point of $M$ and providing a basis for the fiber over each point. Surely, since $G$ is acting by vector bundle maps, each element of $G$ will take such a frame to such a frame.

Now I think I see it: given a local frame $s_1, \dotsc, s_k, s_{k+1}, \dotsc s_{n+k}$ of $E$ such that $s_1, \dotsc, s_k$ is a local frame of $E'$, $G$-invariance of $E$ and $E'$ implies ${g \cdot s_i}$ is a local frame of $E$ such that $g \cdot s_1, \dotsc g \cdot s_k$ is a local frame of $E'$, whence $g$ takes the local frame $[s_{k+1}], \dotsc, [s_{k+n}]$ of $E/E'$ to $g \cdot [s_{k+1}], \dotsc, g \cdot [s_{k+n}]$ which is another local frame of $E/E'$. So smoothness is indeed an automatic consequence of $G$-invariance. Thank you!
